# Uncaught ReferenceError: Required is not define

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to jasmine-karma testing and stuck with some configuration issues. I've been gone through some tutorials and so far I've crated package.json, karma.conf.js and gulpfile.js.

When I try to run the test, it opens the chrome and karma starts to running. But it gives an error as below;

[image: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined]

Here is my gulpfile.js file

```js
'use strict'
var gulp = require('gulp');
var Server = require('karma').Server;


//Run test once and exit
gulp.task('test', function (done){
    new Server(
        {
            configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
            singleRun: false
        }, done).start();
});

// Watch for file changes and re-run tests on each change
gulp.task('tdd', function (done) {
    new Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'
    }, done).start();
});

gulp.task('default', ['tdd']);
```

Here's my karma.conf.js file.

```js
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri Dec 22 2017 16:57:52 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        '*.js'
    ],


    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Here is packages.json

```js
{
  "name": "package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "THis version of the webdriver works with Windows 10 post fall 2005 update",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

Another problem I'm facing is, these tests are going to run locally first and then those tests are going to checked-in to server. How I can test these jasmine tests in the server side? Do I need any addtional setups?

Comment: See [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19059580/6188402)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes will do. Thanks.

Comment: still can't figure out how to apply that to my issue.

Comment: The gulp test created seems wrong somehow. You need to pass options but you are assigning a function object using configFile. Is that an allowed option def?
 http://karma-runner.github.io/2.0/dev/public-api.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to run a client-side test for server-side code (eg. your gulpfile).

Node.js is run on the V8 engine which is also used by google, but has a different global object containing different properties.

In browsers the standard global object is 'window', which for example contains the 'document' property. Therefore `document`, `window.document` and `this.document` are all the same.

Althought if you try to use 'document' in a nodejs environment, you will get the same type error.

**Buttom line** - Google Chrome does not know what 'require' is since it's not a property within the global 'window' object.

Comment: Thank you. Now I can understand the problem here. But do you have any thoughts on how to solving this?

Comment: @Pegasus What exactly is it you're trying to test? The javascript in Node.js and the javascript in Google Chrome run in different environments, and as far as I know, Karma is used for client-side (browser) testing. Although I found this: http://mherman.org/blog/2015/09/10/testing-node-js-with-mocha-and-chai which might help you find a way to test your node.js code.

If you're trying to test your client side code, you must set the `files` property in `karma.conf.js` to: `path/to/client/code/**/*.js`

Comment: I need jasmine to do unit test in AngularJS controllers in visual studio project. I need to figure out how to configure jasmine in visual studio.

Comment: `files: [
        '*.js'
    ],` Isn't this what you're looking for? Just change the path to the `app` folder containing all AngularJS code. For example: `files: [
        './app/**/*.js', './assets/**/*.js`
    ]` etc.